# #apache-flink What are the with options in Flink table/sql api when creating tables by DDL?

Tags: apache-flink

I've been learning Flink table/sql api recently.
One thing that puzzled me a lot is I have no idea how many and kinds "with options"  in DDL . I can't find answers from official website or google.
I'm really upset about it.
Follow with an example ,when creating source table is "connector.type"="filesystem", but when creating a print table is "connector"="print". "connector.type"="print" is wrong.

```
my_source_ddl = """
create table mySource (
    id int,
    temperature float
) with (
    'connector.type' = 'filesystem',
    'format.type' = 'csv',
    'connector.path' = '{}'
)""".format(input_file)
```

```
my_sink_ddl = """
create table mySink (
    id int,
    temperature float
) with (
    'connector' = 'print'
)
""".format(output_file)
```

Why?
Where can i find a doc about elaborating and explaining it ?
Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Available options for each connector are described in Connectors -> Table API Connectors (https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/connectors/table/overview/)

For example, here you can find all available options for kafka connector: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/connectors/table/kafka/#connector-options

filesystem connector is also there.

Comment: thanks s a lot !let me check the doc carefully.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [latest documentation](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/connectors/table/filesystem/#filesystem-sql-connector), it is now `'connector' = 'filesystem'` -- the same as for the other connectors.

Support for `connector.type` was removed in Flink 1.14 along with support for the old connector (pre-FLIP-95) source and sink interfaces. See [FLIP-95: New TableSource and TableSink interfaces](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/x/_hncC) and [FLINK-23063](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-23063) for more details. This is also mentioned in the [Flink 1.14 release notes](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/release-notes/flink-1.14/#remove-tableenvironmentconnect).

Comment: well, finally I realize what my problem is. 
I thought "with" options are descriptions for a table but indeed most or all of them are representing the connector for table source/sink. So better for me to review this character.

Thanks a lot !